# Is this ERD diagram correct?

Tags: sql, relational-database, erd, entity-relationship

The criteria is as follows:

- The bank is organized into branches. Each branch is located in a
  particular city and is identified by a unique name.
- A customer is associated with a particular banker, who may act as
  personal banker for that customer.
- Bank employees (bankers) are identified by their employee-id values.
  The bank administration stores the name and telephone number of each
  employee, address.
- There are some employees whose role is manager. Each manager
  manages a number of employees and each employee reports to his own
  manager. Each branch has only one employee as its manager and each
  employee can manage only one branch and the employees in that
  branch.
- The bank offers two types of accounts saving and current accounts. Both
  types of accounts can be held by more than one customer, e.g. joint
  accounts, and a customer can have more than one account.
- In addition, each savings account has an interest rate, and overdrafts are
  recorded for each current account.

I haven't included any attributes, but are my entities, relations and cardinalities correct?

[image]

Comment: Please give a reference for the style of ERD you are trying to use.

Comment: It is Chen notation

Comment: "Please give a reference." There are lots of variations on Chen. That includes in particular different cardinality notations/conventions. Also please clarify via post edits, not comments. Also please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key.